# scala how to parameterized case class, and pass the case class variable to [T <: Product: TypeTag]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, refactoring

```
// class definition of RsGoods schema
case class RsGoods(add_time: Int)

// my operation
originRDD.toDF[Schemas.RsGoods]()

// and the function definition
def toDF[T <: Product: TypeTag](): DataFrame = mongoSpark.toDF[T]()
```

now i defined too many schemas(RsGoods1,RsGoods2,RsGoods3), and more will be added in the future.

so the question is how to pass a case class as a variable to structure the code

Attach sbt dependency

```
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0",
  "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "2.3.1",
```

Attach the key code snippet

```
  var originRDD = MongoSpark.load(sc, readConfig)
  val df = table match {
    case "rs_goods_multi" => originRDD.toDF[Schemas.RsGoodsMulti]()
    case "rs_goods" => originRDD.toDF[Schemas.RsGoods]()
    case "ma_item_price" => originRDD.toDF[Schemas.MaItemPrice]()
    case "ma_siteuid" => originRDD.toDF[Schemas.MaSiteuid]()
    case "pi_attribute" => originRDD.toDF[Schemas.PiAttribute]()
    case "pi_attribute_name" => originRDD.toDF[Schemas.PiAttributeName]()
    case "pi_attribute_value" => originRDD.toDF[Schemas.PiAttributeValue]()
    case "pi_attribute_value_name" => originRDD.toDF[Schemas.PiAttributeValueName]()
```

Comment: `def abc[T](t: T, clazz: Class[T])` and use it like `abc(t, classOf[T])`.

Comment: toDF is already defined in spark, i cannot change it to abc.

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh the spark version is 2.3.0

Comment: Actually a `DataFrame` is just special name for  untyped `DataSet` which is `DataSet[Row]`. So, `rdd.toDF()` does not take any type-parameters and just returns a `DataSet[Row]`. It is `rdd.toDS[T]` which takes type parameter and returns a `DataSet[T]`. Also just what is your `mongoSpark` ? And what do you mean by "structure the code" ? There are 1000's of ways of "structuring the code". Can you provide an explanation of what exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh toDF function is from MongoSpark, i have to load df with schema type since mongo data is schema free.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185237/discussion-between-suiwenfeng-and-sarvesh-kumar-singh).

Answer (score 1):

From what I have understood about your requirement, i think following should be a decent starting point.

```
def readDataset[A: Encoder](
  spark: SparkSession,
  mongoUrl: String,
  collectionName: String,
  clazz: Class[A]
): Dataset[A] = {
  val config = ReadConfig(
    Map("uri" -> s"$mongoUrl.$collectionName")
  )

  val df = MongoSpark.load(spark, config)

  val fieldNames = clazz.getDeclaredFields.map(f => f.getName).dropRight(1).toList

  val dfWithMatchingFieldNames = df.toDf(fieldNames: _*)

  dfWithMatchingFieldNames.as[A]
}
```

You can use it like this,

```
case class RsGoods(add_time: Int)

val spark: SparkSession = ...

import spark.implicts._

val rdGoodsDS = readDataset[RsGoods](
  spark,
  "mongodb://example.com/database",
  "rs_goods",
  classOf[RsGoods]
)
```

Also, the following two lines,

```
val fieldNames = clazz.getDeclaredFields.map(f => f.getName).dropRight(1).toList

val dfWithMatchingFieldNames = df.toDf(fieldNames: _*)
```

are only required because normally Spark reads DataFrames with column names like `value1, value2, ...`. So we want to change the column names to match what we have in our `case class`.

I am not sure what these "defalut" column names will be because MongoSpark is involved.

You should first check the column names in the df created as following,

```
val config = ReadConfig(
  Map("uri" -> s"$mongoUrl.$collectionName")
)

val df = MongoSpark.load(spark, config)
```

If, MongoSpark fixes the problem of these "default" column names and picks the coulmn names from your collection then those 2 lines will not be required and your method will become just this,

```
def readDataset[A: Encoder](
  spark: SparkSession,
  mongoUrl: String,
  collectionName: String,
): Dataset[A] = {
  val config = ReadConfig(
    Map("uri" -> s"$mongoUrl.$collectionName")
  )

  val df = MongoSpark.load(spark, config)

  df.as[A]
}
```

And,

```
val rsGoodsDS = readDataset[RsGoods](
  spark,
  "mongodb://example.com/database",
  "rs_goods"
)
```

Comment: thanks your patientence, but your idea looks implement the same work of my code. and if more case class defined such as RsGoods1,RsGoods2...RsGoodsN, you should write N "val rsGoodsDS = readDataset[RsGoodsN]", that`s right?

Comment: i just want do it using single line code if possible, and no matter how many case class added.

Comment: Then I will have to say that you are trying to do something strange and somewhat of an anti-pattern. Although that is simply doable, you should reconsider.